# c# gridview doesn't create new rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2013

I have a gridview, a button and a textbox. When a value is entered in the textboxm, on button click that value should appear in the gridview. Everything goes well until I insert a second value. Instead of creating a new row and preserving the data, gridview refreshes the page and inserts the second value in the first value's place.

I was told this has to do with page load, but I don't know how to stop this from happening.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Buton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Name");
  dt.Columns.Add(dc);
  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
  dt.Rows.Add(dr);
  dt.AcceptChanges();
  GridView1.DataSource = dt;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Why you are declaring new table `dt` and add new column at every click

Comment: You're right, I've just realised that. And how could I fix this, if you know? I am new to C# so it's not very easy for me yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net is stateless so you have to manage state of controls, using some state management techniques. e.g session

```
protected void Buton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataTable dt =null;
 if(Session["GridData"]==null)//Initialize a new session only if first time
 {
    dt= new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);
 }
 else 
 {
    dt=Session["GridData"] as DataTable;
 }

  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
  dt.Rows.Add(dr);
  dt.AcceptChanges();
  GridView1.DataSource = dt;
  GridView1.DataBind();
  Session["GridData"]=dt;//save data in session to retrive in next click
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostback)
      {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         ViewState.Add("dt", dt);
      }
}

protected void Buton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Datatable dtable = (Datatable)ViewState["dt"];
  if (ViewState["dt"] == null)
  {
      DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Name");
      dtable.Columns.Add(dc);
  }
      DataRow dr = dtable.NewRow();
      dr["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
      dtable.Rows.Add(dr);
      dtable.AcceptChanges();
      GridView1.DataSource = dtable;
      GridView1.DataBind();
      ViewState["dt"] = dtable;
}
```

Comment: Gives me the next error when I insert the second value :An exception of type 'System.Data.DuplicateNameException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A column named 'Name' already belongs to this DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private DataTable _dataTable;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   InitializeTable();
}
private void InitializeTable()
{        
        if (_dataTable != null) return;
        _dataTable = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Name");
        _dataTable.Columns.Add(dc);
}

protected void Buton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataRow dr = _dataTable.NewRow();
  dr["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
  _dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
  _dataTable.AcceptChanges();
  GridView1.DataSource = _dataTable;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```